# CDI: Which instance's @Observes-method is called ?

Tags: cdi, weld

I observe a strange behavoir for cdi events:

Given the following scenario: An action on the admin page shall update the view  of web page news.xhtml (via omnifaces) by adding the value for "Event-Id":

[image]

Both beans are session scoped backing beans for their jsf based web pages.

> **What happens:** There are two instances of NewsBean due to two browser windows accessing  news.xhtml. When an event is fired, both
>   browser windows are updated. However, **both  updates come from the
>   @Observes-method of the first instance of NewsBean**.

More precisely: NewsBean has a property "id" that is initialized @PostConstruct with a random 
number. This id is displayed on news.xhtml as "Property-Id" (cf. image). The id is also pushed 
by the @Observes-method of the bean and displayed on news.xhtml as "Event-Id":

```
private void onBreakingNews(@Observes Info info) {       
  channel.send(id);  // displayed as "Event-Id" on news.xhtml      
}
```

Let the id's for the two instances simply be 1 and 2. Before the update, browser windows for news.xhtml display:

```
Browser 1:                  Browser 2: 

Property-Id: 1              Property-Id: 2
Event-Id:                   Event-Id:
```

After the update (Event-Id value added):

```
Browser 1:                  Browser 2: 

Property-Id: 1              Property-Id: 2
Event-Id: 1                 Event-Id: 1
```

That means:

- both instances of NewsBean observed the event and updated their associated browser window
- but the data send to the two browsers comes from the @Observes-method of the first instance

I had expected that each instance's own @Observes-method would be called.

> **Q1:** Is this behavoir intended ?
>
> **Q2:** Is the @Observes-method allowed to use internal state of the bean instance ? (in this case it would be a bug)

As cdi container I used Weld from WildFly 11. Code for NewsBean is:

```
@Named @SessionScoped
public class NewsBean {

  private int id; 
  @Inject @Push(channel="pushChannel") private PushContext channel;  

  private void onBreakingNews(@Observes Info info) { 
    // channel.send(info.getMsg()); 
    channel.send(id); 
  } 

  @PostConstruct 
  private void init() { 
    id = new Random().nextInt(100); 
  } 

  ... getter and setter for id ... 
}
```

Code of news.xhtml:

```
<h:head>
  <f:verbatim>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function socketListener(message, channel, event) {
        document.getElementById("formId:info").value = message;
      }; 
    </script>
  </f:verbatim>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:outputText value="Property-Id: "/>
  <h:outputText value="#{newsBean.id}"/>
  <p></p>
  <h:form id="formId">
    <h:outputText value="Event-Id: "/>       
    <h:inputText value="" id="info" readonly="true"/>
    <o:socket channel="pushChannel" onmessage="socketListener"/>       
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Try adding some means of logging into the observer method. I'd say *only one observer method is notified* (that I would expect from CDI) but your `channels` are proliferating the change to all those views

Comment: Yes, I've a println in the observer method and the server log has just one entry from it (in fact that's how I noticed this subject at all). That means, the observer method can use only state that is shared by all bean instances. That's a very important restriction. What annoys me is that this point is never mentioned in CDI literature (for instance, Finnigan's book on Weld loose no word about it).

Comment: Well, CDI is quite a huge spec and integrates on many spots. You cannot hope to have it all written down (plus there are grey areas). besides it might well be written somewhere elsewhere...in another spec and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and give some answer to address your concerns:

> Q1: Is this behavior intended ?

Yes, it is. CDI only picks once observer method (OM) and uses that when it comes to notification. From the top of my head, having multiple OMs, you would introduce some serious troubles with ordering, dependent beans, exception chains and context thread propagation (which spec forbids).

> Q2: Is the @Observes-method allowed to use internal state of the bean instance ? (in this case it would be a bug)

Definitely, and it is not a bug. Imagine it's `@ApplicationScoped` bean. It makes perfect sense to rely on bean's internal state and/or change it. Not to mention it would be near impossible to tell whether observer method's code does access internal state or not.

What happens is that when you fire an event, an observer will be notified within your `current context`. For instance, when having two sessions, you will have at least two contexs. OM will be used for the one within whose context the event was fired.